# Java DataStreams and Sockets

Tags: java, sockets

I'm coding a distributed application in Java using **.net** libraries using sockets and I'm having trouble with the server and the client.

It's a very concrete case. I have a method that reads a String (airport code) and returns the Airport Data.
First I write the code of the operation and the parameters in a DataInputStream and then I send it to the server. On the server I get the parametres and call the method.
Here is the problem; The method can return null if the airport is not found. 
How can I send back the null value to the client?

I have tried with:

```
If the value is null 
then 
   inputStream.writeUtf("Null")
   inputStream.flush()
endif
```

but when I tried to read the value in the client, sometimes I got EOFException

Here are both parts of the code, first the server part:

```
case com.codAeropuerto:  //aeropuerto(codigo : String): DatoAeropuerto

    String codigoAeropuerto = InStr.readUTF();

    DatoAeropuerto aeropuerto = espacioAereo.aeropuerto(codigoAeropuerto);

    if(aeropuerto==null){  //if the value returned is null
            OutStr.writeUTF("NULL");
            OutStr.flush();
    } else {
            OutStr.writeDouble(aeropuerto.coordX);
            OutStr.writeDouble(aeropuerto.coordY);
            OutStr.writeDouble(aeropuerto.coordZ);
            OutStr.flush();
    }
```

and the client part:

```
    try {
        sock=new Socket(server_dir,puerto_server);

        //send petition to server
        DataOutputStream outstr = new DataOutputStream(sock.getOutputStream());
        outstr.writeByte(com.codAeropuerto);
        outstr.writeUTF(codigo);
        outstr.flush();

        //return information
        DataInputStream instr = new DataInputStream(sock.getInputStream());

        if(instr.readUTF().equals("NULL")){
            sock.close()
            return salida;
        }

        double coordX = instr.readDouble();
        double coordY = instr.readDouble();
        double coordZ = instr.readDouble();

        salida = new DatoAeropuerto(coordX,coordY,coordZ);
        sock.close();


    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Error EspacioAereo_Proxy aeropuerto : socket no se ha podido cerrar");

    } return salida;
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `return salida; sock.close();` — This one doesn't compile. `sock.close()` is an unreachable statement, and the compiler will complain about it.

Comment: @MCEmperor sorry, i adapted it on the go, its fixed now and I also added the sock.close() in the client part (if the value is null)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to send back a success/failure code, and only send the name next in the success case.